# Rust Inari crate - Using a generic function with Float as a trait when the type doesn't implement the Float trait

Tags: rust, floating-point, traits, intervals

I am quite new to Rust, so sorry by advance if I'm misunderstanding something.

I have some code in Rust where I have generic functions such as this one :

```
pub(crate) fn square_root<T: Float>(value_array: &[T]) -> T {
    value_array[0].sqrt()
}
```

I also have this macro :

```
macro_rules! print_queries {
    ($INTERVAL:ty, $INTERVAL_INIT:expr, $TYPE_NAME:expr, $METHOD:expr, $PRINT_METHOD:expr, $VARIABLE_COUNT:expr) => {
        {
            let mut used_variables: Vec<$INTERVAL> = Vec::with_capacity($VARIABLE_COUNT);
            for i in 0..$VARIABLE_COUNT {
                used_variables.push($INTERVAL_INIT(COMP_DOUBLES[i]));
            }
            match std::panic::catch_unwind(|| $METHOD(&used_variables)) {
                Ok(result) => {
                    println!("{}: ", $TYPE_NAME);
                    print_query(lower(result), upper(result), $PRINT_METHOD(COMP_GMP_RATIONALS.as_slice()));
                }
                Err(_) => {
                    println!("{}: ", $TYPE_NAME);
                    print_query(1.0, -1.0, $PRINT_METHOD(COMP_GMP_RATIONALS.as_slice()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The macro is used with the first function as the parameter $METHOD, e.g.

`print_queries!(InariInterval, inari_interval, "INARI", square_root, print_square_root, 1);`

As you can see, I'm using this method with the Inari crate, which is a crate for interval arithmetic : https://docs.rs/inari/latest/inari/index.html
InariInterval is a copy of the type inari::Interval, and inari_interval is a method creating an Interval from one float.

However, this does not work, and here is the error I get :

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `inari::Interval: num_traits::Float` is not satisfied
   --> src/query.rs:65:5
    |
65  |     run_query!(square_root, print_square_root, 1, square_root_range, check_input_square_root);
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^-----------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |     |          |
    |     |          required by a bound introduced by this call
    |     the trait `num_traits::Float` is not implemented for `inari::Interval`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `num_traits::Float`:
              f32
              f64
note: required by a bound in `methods::square_root`
   --> src/methods.rs:803:30
    |
803 | pub(crate) fn square_root<T: Float>(value_array: &[T]) -> T {
    |                              ^^^^^ required by this bound in `square_root`
```

I'd like as much as possible to keep my functions generic. I don't think I can implement square_root without using Float, and that would only partly solve the problem since I have other functions with the same issue.

I tried to implement the Float trait for Inari but it doesn't seem to be possible. I got this error : `Only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types [E0117]`

Thus, I'm a little bit stuck and I don't know if I can find a solution while keeping my functions generic.

Thanks for advance for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Unrelated to the actual problem, this macro could be a function (guessed at lots of the signatures) https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cca1726f566f1661c31118c0740a990f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options:

- Ask the inari maintainers to add an impl, possibly behind a feature flag.
- Make your own trait instead of using `Float`.
- Make your own type instead of using `Interval`.

The first would be ideal, but it may not be possible if `Float` is too specific for intervals. Otherwise, the second is probably the best, although you would then be responsible for implementing this trait for existing types, such as `f32`, `f64`, and other crates' floats. The third is similar to the second, but would make you responsible for implementing *existing traits* for your type.

Also, don't use `catch_unwind` unless you absolutely need to. Panics are meant to be unrecoverable, so if you are expecting an error, use an `Option` or `Result` so that truly unrecoverable errors are not ignored.

```rs
pub(crate) fn square_root<T: Float>(value_array: &[T]) -> Option<T> {
    // `first` is the same as `get(0)`
    value_array.first().map(|value| value.sqrt())
}

// inside the macro
match $METHOD(&used_variables) {
    Some(result) => {
        println!("{}: ", $TYPE_NAME);
        print_query(lower(result), upper(result), $PRINT_METHOD(COMP_GMP_RATIONALS.as_slice()));
    }
    None => {
        println!("{}: ", $TYPE_NAME);
        print_query(1.0, -1.0, $PRINT_METHOD(COMP_GMP_RATIONALS.as_slice()));
    }
}
```